# 'Squaring' graph in networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Say I have a graph `G` with with nodes `a, b, c` and edge `(a,b)`. G^2 would have nodes `(a,a), (a,b), (b,b), (a,c)`, etc. and edges `((a,a),(a,b)), ((a,b),(b,b))`, etc. The node pairs are symmetric, so `(a,b) = (b,a)`.

When I implement `G^2` as an adjacency list (using a dictionary) in python, it doesn't take long to get `G^2` from `G`. But now I'm using `NetworkX` and when I try to obtain `G^2`, it takes a long time to run (probably due to a bug?)

So instead of writing my own code, is there a built-in function in NetworkX or a library related to it that constructs `G^2` in the way described above?

Comment: "But now I'm using networkX and when I try to obtain G^2, it takes a long time to run (probably due to a bug?)": Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about a [`Graph power`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_power) for a given graph? In this case you can use a [`power` function](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.product.power.html#networkx.algorithms.operators.product.power) from `NetworkX`:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge('a','b')
g.add_edge('a','c')
g_2 = nx.power(g, 2)
g_2.nodes()
>>>> ['a', 'c', 'b']
g_2.edges()
>>> [('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'b')]
```

Note that this method will not connect unconnected edges, so in code above, if you do not add the edge between 'a' and 'c', you will not get the edges between `c` and any onther edge.